# Sort numbers in left to right in ascending order

Tags: linux, sorting

How to arrange in ascending order from left to right in `vi` or with the `sort` command?
Sample before arrangement:

```
2  3
3  6
5  1
4  2
5  8
```

I want it in this way:

```
2  3
3  6
1  5
2  4
5  8
```

Comment: while read p;do echo $p|tr ' ' '\n'|sort -k1|paste -s -d' ' -;done<input>output

Comment: @krowe Go ahead

Answer (score 0):

This can be one lined with the following command:

```
while read p;do echo $p|tr ' ' '\n'|sort -k1|paste -s -d' ' -;done<input>output
```

Replace input and output with your actual IO files.

I wrote a small script which can be used to test this as well:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script is just for testing purposes. 
# Call this like:

#   sort_numbers numbers.txt numbers_correct.txt

# Where numbers.txt is the file to sort and
# numbers_correct.txt is a file where they are 
# sorted correct.

while read p; do 
  echo $p|tr ' ' '\n'|sort -k1|paste -s -d' ' -
done<$1>output.$1

# This just compares the output with the correct output
file1=$2
file2=output.$1
echo -n $file1 and $file2 are' ' && cmp --silent $file1 $file2 && echo the same || echo different
```